# useState not working when receiving new values from Redux Store in Function Component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, formik, redux-toolkit

On this [StackBlitz (you can play with)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-edqkfk?file=src%2FApp.js) I have the following code:

**App.js**

```
import { Field, Form, Formik } from 'formik';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Provider, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import store, { userActions } from './store';

const Suggestion = () => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { color } = useSelector(state => state.user);

  return (color === 'Yellow') ? (
    <div>
      We recommend you to change to Green.<br />
      <a href="#" onClick={() => { dispatch(userActions.save({ color: 'Green' })); }}>Change Now!</a>
    </div>
  ) : null;
};

const MyComp = () => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const userData = useSelector(state => state.user);

  const initialValues = {
    color: 'Green',
  };

  const [ formValues, setFormValues ] = useState((userData.length > 0) ? userData : initialValues);

  console.log(JSON.stringify({ userData, formValues }));

  const onSubmit = (values) => {
    dispatch(userActions.save(values));
  };

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={formValues}
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
      enableReinitialize
    >
      {formik => {

        const handleChange = (partialUserData) => {
          setFormValues({
            ...formValues,
            ...partialUserData
          });
          formik.submitForm();
        };

        return (
          <Form>
            <h2>What Color do you use?</h2>
            <Field id="color" as="select" value={formValues.color} onChange={(e) => { handleChange({ color: e.target.value }); }}>
              <option value=''>Select...</option>
              <option value='Green'>Green</option>
              <option value='Yellow'>Yellow</option>
            </Field>
            <Suggestion />
          </Form>
        );
      }}
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <MyComp />
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

**store.js**

```
import { configureStore, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState: {},
  reducers: {
    save(state, action) {
      for (const key in action.payload) {
        state[key] = action.payload[key];
      }
    },
  },
});

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: userSlice.reducer,
  },
  devTools: true,
});

export const userActions = userSlice.actions;

export default store;
```

**Expected functionality**

1. "Green" is selected by default
2. You select "Yellow" and a suggestion appears underneath (you get: "Yellow" on the console)
3. You select "Green" and the suggestion disappears (you get: "Green" on the console)
4. Do Step 2 above
5. You click the link: "Change Now!"
6. Option "Green" gets selected and the suggestion disappears (you get: "Green" on the console)

**My Problem is:**

Step 6 is not totally working because even though the suggestion disappears which is fine, the option: "Green" doesn't get selected and on the console I still get: "Yellow".

For some reason, the line...

```
const [ formValues, setFormValues ] = useState(...);
```

... is not saving values from the Store on variable: `formValues` since the `userData` has the expected values as you can see on the image below...

[image]

Any idea on how to make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no that is wrong `React.useState(defaultValue)` it's just the default value for the `React.useState` which is used on component render and it does not listen for new changes.

You need to use `React.useEffect()` hook which takes the dependencies array if you leave the dependencies array empty then `useEffect` will only be invoked once on component render but if you pass dependency as your redux data then every time your dependency data is changed `useEffect` will be invoked.

So finally you code will be like this

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const userData = useSelector(state => state.user);

  const initialValues = {
    color: 'Green',
  };

  const [ formValues, setFormValues ] = useState(initialValues);
  
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    setFormValues((userData.length > 0) ? userData : initialValues);
    // cleanup function which will be invoked on component unmount
    return ()=> {
      setFormValues(userData)
    }
  },[useData]);

  console.log(JSON.stringify({ userData, formValues }));

  const onSubmit = (values) => {
    dispatch(userActions.save(values));
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the correct way to capture the new stored value. But what i can suggest is to create a useEffect hooks to set new form values that runs every time `userData` changes.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setFormValues(userData)
  }, [userData])
```